# Why div element do not move upwards when the div above it is floated left?

Tags: html, css, web, css-float

i have been studying float property in **CSS**.

**This is my html code:**

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}
.normal {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <img src="Icon.png">
  <h1>hi my name is left</h1> 
  <p>hi im a paragraph of abcd. ghjtyj yttyrkutk ukuykyilt uk</p>
</div>
<div class="normal">
  <img src="Icon.png">
  <h1>hi my name is normal</h1> 
  <p>hi im a paragraph of abcd. ghjtyj yttyrkutk ukuykyilt uk</p>
</div>
```

i want to know why my `div` with class normal is not moving upwards with the `div` of **class left?**

I asked this question because if i write a

```
<p>something</p>
```

after my `div` of class left the content of `p tag` moves **upwards** but this is not happening with a `div`..
I want to why this is **happening?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first div is 25% wide, so it takes up 25% of the available space horizontally.
The second div is also 25% wide; therefore the first div takes up all the space that the second one would take up. There simply is no more room to the right!

Solution: make the second div not 25% wide, but 50% (25% more than the first).

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}
.normal {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <img src="Icon.png">
  <h1>hi my name is left</h1> 
  <p>hi im a paragraph of abcd. ghjtyj yttyrkutk ukuykyilt uk</p>
</div>
<div class="normal">
  <img src="Icon.png">
  <h1>hi my name is normal</h1> 
  <p>hi im a paragraph of abcd. ghjtyj yttyrkutk ukuykyilt uk</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer ! But I thought that the dimensions point needed some more explanation, so I have added my own ...

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Gopal Singh Rathore

I believe I have understood your question correctly.

The reason for this is because the width is set on the div which also have a display:block, if you changed the display:block to flex for example it will then appear alongside it. If you also set a width on the p tag it will do the same as the div.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The **normal** div moves to the top, the normal contents do not: See the **normal** extension:

Mr Lister gives you the solution: you need to make **normal** wider so that the contents will fit to the right of **left**

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}
.normal {
  text-align: center;
  width: 27%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <img src="Icon.png">
  <h1>hi my name is left</h1> 
  <p>hi im a paragraph of abcd. ghjtyj yttyrkutk ukuykyilt uk</p>
</div>
<div class="normal">
  <img src="Icon.png">
  <h1>hi my name is normal</h1> 
  <p>hi im a paragraph of abcd. ghjtyj yttyrkutk ukuykyilt uk</p>
</div>
```